# ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, mount, usb-drive

When I try to mount my 1tb hard drive /dev/sda I get

```
"exited with non-zero exit status 21: ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy"
```

I have tried using the

```
"sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=matt,gid=users,umask=0022 /dev/sda2 /mnt/a/"
```

command for this and the GUI file manager Dolphin.

lsblk output:

```
sda                   8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk   
├─sda1                8:1    0   100M  0 part   
├─sda2                8:2    0 931.4G  0 part   
└─pdc_cfffhahgfg    253:3    0 931.3G  0 dmraid 
  └─pdc_cfffhahgfg1 253:4    0   100M  0 part   
sdb                   8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk   
├─sdb1                8:17   0   500M  0 part   /boot
└─sdb2                8:18   0 111.3G  0 part   
  ├─fedora-swap     253:0    0   7.8G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
  ├─fedora-root     253:1    0    50G  0 lvm    /
  └─fedora-home     253:2    0  53.6G  0 lvm    /home
```

The df command does not even show the drive / partition(s).

I am on Fedora linux 22. 4.0.8-300.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 10 21:04:56 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you using a cluster environment? If yes, please check if the device has been using by another node.
2. Also please make sure /dev/sda2 has a correct format.
3. The "df" command only shows which are already mounted.

Comment: 1. No. I am on a home computer. 
2. How would I do this?
3. Sorry. Didn't know.

Comment: If you're a home user, that'll be pretty easy, attach your device to a windows PC, see if it can mount and access properly.

Comment: Any other way to do this? I don't currently have a working windows system. I had Windows installed before installing Fedora (just installed) and the drive had worked up to that point. It was a secondary drive btw / not the boot drive. 
 Thank!

Comment: You may tried to use this command to check if the partition is ok: ntfs-3g.probe --readwrite /dev/sda2

Comment: I get no output on doing that command. I had to remove the last - for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I seem to have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the drive. All I had to do was check the partition with a partition editor and it fixed it. Hopefully this will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when I tried to use a drive that was once in a linux software raid array.  Even though I removed the existing partition and created a new one with type 7 (NTFS) it kept thinking the drive was part of a raid array.  The linux raid signature remained on the disk.

I used the wipefs utility...

```
sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdc
```

... then recreated the partition, formatted, rebooted, and mounted.

For more info see...

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-wipefs-to-wipe-a-signature-from-disk-on-linux/